# Node PostgreSQL Update issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am getting some odd behavior when trying to update a record in PG from Node. When I try to update with the code/route below I get no error on POST but the record simply doesn't update. Am I missing anything here? Disclaimer - I am new to Node ;)

```
router.post('/:id/edit', function(req, res, next){

    var bookid = req.params.id;
    var bookname = req.body.bookname;

    pg.connect(dbconnect, function(err, client, done) {

        //update book
        client.query('UPDATE books SET bookname='+bookname+' WHERE id='+bookid+'', function(err, result) {

            //display edit form
            client.query('SELECT * FROM books WHERE id='+bookid+'', function(err, result) {
                res.render('bookedit',{ title: 'Edit Book SUCESS!', book: result.rows });
                done();
            });

        });

    });

});
```

My error console shows:

```
{ [error: column "bookly" does not exist]
  name: 'error',
  length: 106,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42703',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '27',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '3090',
  routine: 'errorMissingColumn' }
POST /books/2/edit 200 19.914 ms - 447
```

My DB schema:

[image]

ANSWER:

Query string should be:

```
client.query('UPDATE books SET bookname=($1) WHERE id=($2)',[thebookname, bookid], function(err, result) {

            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }

            //display edit form
            client.query('SELECT * FROM books WHERE id='+bookid+'', function(err, result) {
                res.render('bookedit',{ title: 'Edit Book SUCESS!', book: result.rows });
                done();
            });

        });
```

Comment: Did you check `err` parameter value of update query callback? Maybe something helpful there. Also whether or not book id needs to be wrapped in quotes in where condition or not?

Comment: Yes great idea. Thanks. updated the question. It seems its trying to use the post data to search for the col name? Not sure why.

Comment: Could be because your `id` is invalid or non-existing. You can verify the result by appending your `UPDATE` with `RETURNING *` to see what got actually updated, if anything. Also, `result.rowCount` tells you how many records were in fact updated.

Comment: From your update, the queries you show in the example clearly do not correspond to what you are actually using, because the error is very clear - you are using an invalid column name.

Comment: Thanks for your help @vitaly-t I updated with a shot of my schema showing that the col name is good > 'bookname' I have no idea what I get { [error: column "bookly" does not exist] in my console.

Comment: This happens what you use manual query concatenation instead of proper query formatting. You end up with all kinds of garbage in the query string that's not properly formatted. I'm betting that's exactly what's happening. Log the query into the console before executing it, and you will see.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t as I mentioned I am a bit of a noob to Node. I would love some advice on patterns or best practices ;)

Comment: My query to console was > UPDATE books SET bookname=Booker WHERE id=1 which seems good, no?

Comment: Got it thank you @vitaly-t question updated with answer

Comment: If it's really without quotes it will expect to find a column `Booker` in that case. Should be `'Booker'`